# Are these two lines of PHP different?

Tags: php

I'm looking through a code base. This is one of the lines.

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/a_script.php' );
```

I'm considering rewriting it as:

```
require_once( './a_script.php' );
```

Are those two lines of code any different?

Comment: You should also consider writing it as `require_once __DIR__ . '/a_script.php';`. Parentheses around `require` / `include` args are discouraged

Comment: Discouraged for what reason?

Comment: @LincolnB "Note: include_once and require_once are statements, not functions. Parentheses should not surround the subject filename."

Comment: In that case, why does PHP even allow you to use `require / include` like they are functions?

Comment: Because newbies get confused and think they are functions thus putting them in parentheses.

Comment: See [Example #4](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-140)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are different. The second one is relative to the working directory, which is not always the same thing as the directory the currently executing file is in.

For the most part, the working directory is the directory of the *original file*. If you are running the require_once in a file that is being included by another file, the path is relative the first file.

Answer (score 4):

They have some different

```
// '/dir/index.php'
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/script.php' ); // '/dir/script.php'
require_once( './script.php' ); // '/dir/script.php'

chdir('/')
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/script.php' ); // '/dir/script.php'
require_once( './script.php' ); // '/script.php'
```